# DialogFragment not visible but selectable

Tags: java, android, fragment, dialogfragment

I have a very strange problem on Android using `DialogFragments`. 
I have a `FrameLayout` with no content and the `OnClickListener` set to open a `FragmentDialog` where the user can choose what type of content he wants to add. 
If I choose an image from the gallery, this image will be loaded and an image view inside the Frame-Layout is created and the image is shown. If the user clicks again on the layout the selection dialog should open again and the user can select a new image and the old one would be replaced.

This works quite well on my device with Android 4.1. But if I test it on Android 2.3 something strange happens:
The first dialog appears and the user can choose an image from the gallery. But if the user clicks again the dialog is not shown again. But the display becomes darker as if the dialog would be there but is not shown. If I click on the position where the selection dialog should be the gallery is started again. So the dialog is definitely there, but it is simply not shown.

I have tried almost everything that came to my mind(and what I found in the internet) to fix this issue, but it does not help anything. Of course I am using the support library to import the Fragment and `DialogFragment`.

I start this dialog from a Fragment which is embedded in a `ViewPager`. So it is basically a tabbed view. What's interesting: I I run into this bug and the display is just getting darker but no dialog is visible, I can cancel the invisible dialog and just drag the `ViewPager` a bit to left or right(to the next fragment) and if I get back and click on the content again the dialog is shown again. 
But if I am dragging the `ViewPager` around there are no log messages so I have no idea why the dialog is suddenly visible again if I firstly move the page(only a bit is enough).

Here is some of my code:

in the onCreateView method I do the following:

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT_TYPE), container, false);
editorActivity = ((NoteEditorActivity) EditorSectionFragment.this.getActivity());

// ...    

if( fragmentId == R.layout.fragment_note_preferences_editor ){
            // the other page
else if( fragmentId == R.layout.fragment_note_editor ) {
            final View addLeftElement = rootView.findViewById( R.id.addLeftElement );
            final View addRightElement = rootView.findViewById( R.id.addRightElement );
            final View addTopElement = rootView.findViewById( R.id.addTopElement );
            final View addBottomElement = rootView.findViewById( R.id.addBottomElement );

            final FrameLayout contentLayout = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById( R.id.contentLayout );

            showNavigation(editorActivity, contentLayout, editorActivity.currentPosition.x, editorActivity.currentPosition.y);

            contentLayout.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("CONTENT CREATOR", "create new element at " + editorActivity.currentPosition);

                    //((NoteEditorActivity) EditorSectionFragment.this.getActivity()).showContentSelectionDialog();
                    ((NoteEditorActivity) EditorSectionFragment.this.getActivity()).showCameraChooseDialog();
                }

            });
}
```

`showCameraChoose`(I also did it without the `FragmentTransaction`, but this didn't work either)

```
protected void showCameraChooseDialog() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("cameraChoose");
    if( prev != null ){
        Log.i("PREVIOUS", "Remove previous dialog");
        ft.remove(prev);
    }

    (new CameraSelectionDialog()).show( ft, "cameraChoose");    
}
```

CameraSelectionDialog:

```
public static class CameraSelectionDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {           
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Camera", "Gallery"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( this.getActivity() );
        builder.setTitle("Choose how to get the image!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if( which == 0){
                    ((NoteEditorActivity)(getActivity())).startCamera();
                    CameraSelectionDialog.this.dismiss();
                }
                else{ 
                    ((NoteEditorActivity)(getActivity())).startGallery();
                    CameraSelectionDialog.this.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        return builder.create();

    }
}
```

The `startGallery` method simply starts an gallery intent:

```
protected void startGallery() {
    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , ActionCodes.GALLERY_ACTION_CODE);
}
```

This image is handled in the `onActivityResult` method. But it does not matter what I choose to do in the `onActivityResult` method. Even if I don't create the image, the problem occurs.

I have no idea what I can do to solve this problem and I hope that maybe you can think of a reason for this strange bug. I am grateful for any advice or hint what could be wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try to call ft.addToBackStack(null).commit(); before (new CameraSelectionDialog()).show( ft, "cameraChoose");

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. If I call commit I will get an error,since show will call commit again. If I don't call it, the problem still exists.